# How can I access the WMS address at this address?

Tags: wms, mapping, tile-map-service

How can I access the WMS tile map address at this address?

https://adres.nvi.gov.tr/Proxy/MapServer/export?F=image&FORMAT=PNG8&TRANSPARENT=true&SIZE=772%2C948&BBOX=3646477.6363953245%2C4833305.907624307%2C3646708.141808747%2C4833588.963494676&BBOXSR=3857&IMAGESR=3857&DPI=90

Comment: Duplicate post https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/420920/wms-tms-resolve-help please on ask one question (please delete one question).

Comment: Do you mean tiled WMS (web map service), or WMTS (web map tile service)?  They are not the same thing.  If you are unsure, then perhaps adding more context to the question would help.  Eg, what are you planning to do with the service; how to wish to use it; in which software?

Comment: If I can access any of the addresses of the relevant map such as wms, wmts, xyz, I want to open it in GIS programs. Mapinfo, arcmap, qgis etc.

Comment: sorry for translate; I access https://adres.nvi.gov.tr/VatandasIslemleri/AdresSorgu from this address. If I open the page for the first time, it redirects to the homepage, if I go to the same address (https://adres.nvi.gov.tr/VatandasIslemleri/AdresSorgu) again with the "sorgula" button, the map opens.

Comment: When I follow the f12 > network tab on google chrome on the map that opens, I can see this address in the renewed data in the map content. https://adres.nvi.gov.tr/Proxy/MapServer/export?F=image&FORMAT=PNG8&TRANSPARENT=true&SIZE=150%2C948&BBOX=3706232.512522882%2C4309581.315081438%2C3889681.3804073045%2C5468978.160110991&BBOXSR=3857&IMAGESR=3857&DPI=90

Comment: If I convert this address to https://adres.nvi.gov.tr/Proxy/MapServer/ and add wms to the end, arcmap can access the URL but not the URI. layers are empty. I tried to open the address in sources such as arcgis map service, wms, wmts, qgis (xyz), but unfortunately I could not get a positive result. I emptied the bbox part to see all the data, it still didn't work. I don't know the forum rules either. i am new. No one is helping.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: that isn't a WMS endpoint, it's similar to but not WMS

Comment: Too many wms words are repeated in the page source. So i thought of it as wms. How can I access the source map?

Answer (score 4):

That URL does not seem to be a WMS (or WMTS) server, but rather an ArcGIS Server mapservice. The IMAGESR parameter is specific for the ArcGIS [export map](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/enterprise/export-map.htm) function.

That said, the proxy seems to be configured in a way to block access to most of the ArcGIS Server REST api, and allowing only map images to be exported. This means that for instance, it is not possible to retrieve a list of layers in the service, and therefore, ArcGIS, and probably most other software, will not be able to access it.

Comment: Can I customize portable basemap server and use it on this uri?

Comment: @saroman Sorry, I don't know Portable Basemap Server. You could [ask](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) a separate question about that.